# unknown attribute 'service_name' for ActiveStorage::Blob

Tags: ruby-on-rails-6

After I upgraded from Rails 5 to 6.1, the ActiveStorage raises an error:

`unknown attribute 'service_name' for ActiveStorage::Blob`.

Why, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 75):

These commands worked for me.

```
rails active_storage:update
rails db:migrate
```

Comment: Where you found these two commands? I think so is good to open an issue on rails to they add it on doc. Specifically, this doc: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading_ruby_on_rails.html#upgrading-from-rails-5-2-to-rails-6-0

Comment: I'm not sure where I found them. I imagine it was from some document or rails release.

Comment: I just upgraded from rails 5.2 to rails 6.0 and had this issue. Running the commands didn't help. But I just kept upgrading and when I got to rails 6.1 it went away.

Comment: Worked for me! A small note, in production, after migrating the db for the new columns, I had to restart the application before it would work (otherwise it gave the same error). I did so on heroku with `heroku restart`, but that will differ depending on hosting)

Answer (score 31):

Gemfile without the error:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.0.2'
```

Gemfile with the error:

```
gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'master'
```

If you were already using active_storage and want to update your rails version to 6.1.0alpha, you have to run

```
rails active_storage:update
```

this will give you 2 new active_storage migrations that are needed for active_storage to work properly.

Migration 1:

```
# This migration comes from active_storage (originally 20190112182829)
class AddServiceNameToActiveStorageBlobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    unless column_exists?(:active_storage_blobs, :service_name)
      add_column :active_storage_blobs, :service_name, :string

      if configured_service = ActiveStorage::Blob.service.name
        ActiveStorage::Blob.unscoped.update_all(service_name: configured_service)
      end

      change_column :active_storage_blobs, :service_name, :string, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Migration 2:

```
# This migration comes from active_storage (originally 20191206030411)
class CreateActiveStorageVariantRecords < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def up
    create_table :active_storage_variant_records do |t|
      t.belongs_to :blob, null: false, index: false
      t.string :variation_digest, null: false

      t.index %i[ blob_id variation_digest ], name: "index_active_storage_variant_records_uniqueness", unique: true
      t.foreign_key :active_storage_blobs, column: :blob_id
    end
  end
end
```

Than you just run

```
rails db:migrate
```

It works.

Comment: this should be trending now as everybody will be upgrading from rails 6.0 to rails 6.1

Answer (score 10):

This is taken care of in the normal upgrade process:

```
rails app:update
rails db:migrate
```

This solution to the `service_name` change gets a mention in the [6.1 Release Notes](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/6_1_release_notes.html#active-storage-notable-changes). The `rails app:update` task calls the internal `rails active_storage:update` for you since Rails 6.0.0 ([source](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/40791#issuecomment-742776097)).

Answer (score -1):

step 1:

```
 rm 20191021084642_create_active_storage_tables.active_storage.rb
```

step 2:

```
 rails active_storage:install
```

step 3:

```
 rails db:migrate
```

Comment: wouldnt that delete all your attachments?