# Heroku Ruby Website Image Uploading Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Trying to set up image uploading on my website, but whenever I test uploading an image, it fails and I get these errors in the log... I've looked through so many fixes but none seem to work correctly.

If anyone could point me towards a fix or let me know what exactly is going wrong that would be great. Thanks.

````
2021-04-18T19:33:58.653571+00:00 app[web.1]: [6e2d06ab-891e-4970-8fbe-2e9fb2868eca] ActiveModel::UnknownAttributeError (unknown attribute 'service_name' for ActiveStorage::Blob.):
2021-04-18T19:33:58.653571+00:00 app[web.1]: [6e2d06ab-891e-4970-8fbe-2e9fb2868eca]
2021-04-18T19:33:58.653572+00:00 app[web.1]: [6e2d06ab-891e-4970-8fbe-2e9fb2868eca] app/controllers/gigs_controller.rb:88:in `upload_photo'
2021-04-18T19:33:58.748015+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2021-04-18T19:33:58.747897 #4]  INFO -- : [16714095-28f1-4c97-8e78-407316f869dd] Started GET "/gigs/6/edit?step=4" for [ip address] at 2021-04-18 19:33:58 +0000```
````

Comment: Can you provide some code snippets from the part of the code where the error happens? It says in `gigs_controller.rb` at line 88

Comment: Are you saving uploads to a service like Amazon S3, or to the local filesystem?

Comment: this didn't help at all? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58373159/unknown-attribute-service-name-for-activestorageblob