# Rails couldn't find a valid model for ActiveStorage::Blob association, while trying to use activeadmin and active storage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, rails-activestorage

I've:

1. Set up a rails project
2. Added Active Admin.
3. Set up Active Storage, updating the configuration to connect locally and doing:

   bin/rails active_storage:install
   bin/rails db:migrate

Then when trying to set up a very simple model `Document` with a file attached:

```
class Document < ApplicationRecord
    has_one_attached :file
end
```

And the most simple Active Admin page possible for it:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Document do
  permit_params :name, :type, :file
end
```

I'm getting the following error when trying to access the page:

> Rails couldn't find a valid model for ActiveStorage::Blob association.
> Please provide the :class_name option on the association declaration.
> If :class_name is already provided, make sure it's an
> ActiveRecord::Base subclass.

I'm unsure what is going wrong. It seems from the docs everything should work after the migration and adding that line to the model.

Ruby version: "3.1.1"
Rails version: "7.0.2"

Comment: For me, restarting the server fixed the issue.

Comment: I had a similar error (after upgrading from rails 6 to 7), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59828575/5783745) solved for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I run into the same issue, and found out that this answer fixed the issue for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72005456/583560

> [...]adding an initializer with the following worked (Rails 6.0.4.7):
>
> ```
> Rails.application.reloader.to_prepare do
>  ActiveStorage::Blob
> end
> ```